# serialized the Ajax returned result in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function(){
      setInterval(function(){
         $.ajax({
             url: "getResult.php",

             success: function(results){

             var details = results.serializeArray();    //Serialized Here

             var output = '<tr><td>Name</td>\n\
                           <td>Type</td>\n\
                           <td>Data</td>\n\
                           <td>Detail</td></tr>';

             $.each(results, function(i, result){                               
                 output += '<tr><td>' +  result.Name + '</td><td>' 
                                      +result.Type + '</td><td>' 
                                      +result.data + '</td><td>
                                      <a href=javascript:newPopup("test.php?detail='+details +'")>Detail</a></td></tr>';       //pass serialized value here
             });

             $("#insideTable").html(output);

             }, dataType: "json"});
        }, 2000);
});

</script>
```

I would like to serialized the Ajax returned result and also pass it to the link as query string.

However, it doesn't work and the console report error is `results.serializeArray is not a function`.

Welcome any help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Please can you add to your question the output from `console.log(results);` .... you will need to add that after `success: function(results){`

Answer (score 1):

If `results` is a JSON string (which judging by how you are trying to use it makes me think it is) you need to use

```
var result jQuery.parseJSON(results);
```

this will return an `Object` where you can use `result.` syntax

Note: the reason why you are getting `serializeArray is not a function` is because the jQuery function `serializeArray()` expects to a jQuery object to run - ie `$(results).serializeArray()`

Answer (score 0):

method `serializeArray()` can be applied (chained) to a jQuery element (what is `results`?) and, since you are inside an object, you will also get a parse error (you should write `details : results.serializeArray(),` instead)

Comment: results is the Ajax resulted array

Comment: read docs about it: http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/ - as you can see that method is applied to a jQuery collection of nodes

Answer (score 0):

The .serializeArray() method creates a JavaScript array of objects, ready to be encoded as a JSON string. It operates on a jQuery object representing a set of form elements. You are getting this error because you are passing something wrong in `$results`.

see http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray for working example..

Answer (score 0):

the results.serializeArray is not getting called cause it's not part of `$.ajax` try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function(){
     $.ajax({
         url: "getResult.php",

         success: function(results){
         var output = '<tr><td>Name</td>\n\
                       <td>Type</td>\n\
                       <td>Data</td>\n\
                       <td>Detail</td></tr>';
var details = results.serializeArray();


         }, dataType: "json"});
    }, 2000);
});
```

also you're gona find a parse error on `<a href=javascript:newPopup("test.php? 
    detail='+details +'")>Detail</a></td></tr>';`

Comment: `the results.serializeArray is not getting called cause it's not part of $.ajax` WHAT ??? read the help for [serializeAray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

Comment: lol have you read this http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ ? you were putting the var details = results.serializeArray(); before the success fonction

Comment: serializeArray is part of jquery not part of $.ajax --'

Comment: yes and you need a jQuery object ... its a method  ... `results.serializeArray()` wont work ... as `results` is not a jQuery object

Comment: did you tried what i suggested ? you were calling results.serializeArray() before the success fonction of $.Ajax which initialize the results object so all you have to do is calling results.serializeArray() inside the success fonction

Comment: again .. im not the person who asked the question ... and if you read the question again the `results.serializeArray()` is within the `success` function ! its got nothing to do with where it is placed - its a function of jQuery not of Array or String or whatever the type of `results` is ...

Comment: he updated it after i wrote the response (and sorry i thought you were him)

Comment: it will work no matter what you call the object as long as it's name is the same specified in the success fonction (unless you try it please don't say it won't work cause i'm working with it at this moment )